# using PHP in iphone

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

Hey friend as you know  I am new in iphone I didn't know any think about can anyone help me.
Can I use PHP in iPhone for storing music file And get get this file again when ever I need this any one who can help out this condition or give some hint to solve this 
Previously I also put one question about this.But it is with the cloud server using in iphone 
please help me friends .

Comment: possible duplicate of [music appplication in iphone ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482420/music-appplication-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to natively run on the iPhone, no. PHP is a server side script for web development, you can have a website developed with it and access that website using the iPhone just fine. As far as uploading from the iPhone you cannot do that either as Safari does not have access to the file system. If needed you could develop a custom application that would allow uploads to your website.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side scripting language, iPhone uses Objective-c, it means the answer to your question is Plain "NO", well you can always go with other way round, you can create a iphone optimized web application using PHP and Javascript, and access it in your iPhone using the web browser like safari.